# Do path parameters in jax-rs @Path expression need to be slash-separated?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm inspecting some code in a JAX-RS springboot microservice that I'm starting to work on.  I saw the following (modified):

```
@POST
@Path("{foo: ([^/]+?)?}{bar: (/[^/]+?)?}")
public Response doit(
        @PathParam("foo") String foo,
        @PathParam("bar") String bar,
        @RequestBody UpdateRequest updateRequest, @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders);
```

That @Path value looks odd.  Instead of having explicit "/" markers in the string, it's trying to do it through the regex.  I'm guessing this can work, because this is existing code, but is this really advisable?  Is there any reason that this would be necessary?

I suppose a similar questionable example would be this:

```
@Path("foo{bar: (/[^/]+?)?}")
```

Is there any reason this is better than the simpler:

```
@Path("foo/{bar}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf), specifically the “URI Templates” section under the Resources chapter, has the answer:

> Template parameters can optionally specify the regular expression used to match their values. The default value matches any text and terminates at the end of a path segment but other values can be used to alter this behavior, e.g.:
>
> ```
> @Path("widgets/{path:.+}")
> public class Widget {
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> In the above example the `Widget` resource class will be matched for any request whose path starts with `widgets` and contains at least one more path segment; the value of the `path` parameter will be the request path following `widgets`. E.g. given the request path `widgets/small/a` the value of path would be `small/a`.

So, if you don’t provide a customn regex, the default boundary is the `/`.

Therefore, that complex regex is unnecessary.  `@Path("{foo}/{bar}"` is fine.

Technically, it’s not exactly the same;  the regex forces `{bar}` to include the leading `/`.  Is it worth the complexity of regexes that need extra visual analysis?  Not in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you just used

```
@Path("foo/{bar}")
```

then calling `/foo` would lead to a 404, because the `/` is static and it would require requesting `/foo/`. But when it's in the regex of `bar`, it makes it optional. So the example

```
@Path("foo{bar: (/[^/]+?)?}")
```

allows you to access the parent resource *and* the sub resource from the same resource method. As a more realistic example say you have

```
@Path("customers{id: (/[^/]+?)?}")
```

With this, we would have a resource method that could handle both accessing a collection resource *and* an single resource. As opposed to having two separate resource methods, one for each case. For example

```
@GET
@Path("customers{id: (/[^/]+?)?}")
public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return collection customers collection
    } else {
        fetch custom by id and return customer.
    }
}
```

That's the only real benefit I can see in this situation. Would probably need more context, maybe some documenting comments from the author as to what they were trying to accomplish. Overall though, IMO the code looks unnecessarily over complicated.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the value extracted for the "bar" property will include an initial "/"? Is there some reason this has to be in the regexp?

Comment: If it wasn't, then it wouldn't be optional.